# Is this GitHub/linguist question off-topic?

Tags: discussion, support, scope, vote-to-close

I just asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42724465/6850771) and a user immediately commented "this is off-topic". It now has two close votes ("not about programming"). However, the question is about GitHub's linguist, and the answer is about adding a line to the `.gitattributes` file. GitHub, linguist, and `.gitattributes` are all about programming.

Is this question off-topic? If so, why?

**Update** I tried to close it as a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34713765/github-changes-repository-to-wrong-language) but instead I got it closed as off-topic. Why is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34713765/github-changes-repository-to-wrong-language) not off-topic, but mine was?

Comment: Your question has a load of points to improve. But it's not really _off-topic_ IMO.

Comment: How a particular website performed some opaque task or how to get that website to reverse the results of this task aren't really programming related.  Yeah, it's a tool used by developers, but how GitHub implements their linguist or how they handle changing the results is off topic here.  You should bring it up with GitHub, they're probably the only folks who can help you.

Comment: "Why does a web do what it does" raises hackles.  The obvious way to get ahead is by googling "github linguist attributes".  First hit tells you everything you need.  Do we still need the question?  Are you going to maintain the answer for the next twenty years?

Comment: Hah, Good choice :)

Comment: @HansPassant, since when is commitment to a 20-year answer maintenance window a requirement for a question to be on-topic? And there's lots of Google-able questions which are still on-topic. While I think the quality of this question is worth debating, I'm not really getting the point you're trying to make with those assertions.

Comment: Not so sure why this is not obvious.  GitHub already documents this, easy to find, duplicating it just isn't very useful and if we do anyway then we have a maintenance headache.

Comment: @HansPassant, come on. I can list about a hundred "on-topic" StackOverflow questions that "should have been obvious".

Comment: We're talking about my comment, not your question.

Comment: @MDXF I'm sure there are a lot more than 100 bad SO questions out there.  The existence of other bad questions doesn't mean it's okay to ask more bad questions.

Comment: Side note: zero is very high score for a question that has immediate answer if one tried  to search - https://www.bing.com/search?q=github+specify+language (ignoring on-topic part of the discussion).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov First result: 30 votes

Comment: @MDXF exactly my point - your question should have received at least -5 to -10 votes for not demonstrating any research. I see no reasons to complain about zero score closed question in this case. Indeed it can be re-opened and properly downvoted - but why would you want it?

Answer (score -4):

GitHub is a tool that is supported and maintained by someone, and not some "general" thing like C or C++ that is not likely to change.

Consider the difference between question "How can I dial an international number with a cellphone" and "How to add international dialing feature on my Samsung brick". People would be happy to help you out with the first question while you probably want to turn to customer service for the second one.

Well, this analogy is as hard to judge as your situation.

Comment: All tools are supported and maintained by someone unless they are abandonware, and all languages have actual (potentially buggy) compilers or interpreters that it is meaningful to ask about. Or are gcc optimization questions suddenly off-topic? How about Python? Maybe Visual Studio macros aren't a thing SO will support? Guess we'd better take all those MySQL and SQL Server questions somewhere else, along with jQuery, node.js, TypeScript, and of course we can't forget MATLAB, which is maintained by MathWorks!